# MATLAB Data Interpolation - Basics

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have a dataset consisting of a position and a signal - the signal is sampled at scattered positions (0, 115, 230....):

```
0   1.709219858
115 1.676595745
230 1.643026005
345 1.609456265
460 1.574940898
575 1.540898345
690 1.506855792
806 1.473286052
```

I would like to smooth this data and then interpolate it to fill in the intervening positions i.e.:

```
0   x
1   x
2   x
3   x
4   x
5   x
6   x
7   x
8   x
9   x
10  x
```

Where x is the smoothed signal. I've been smoothing data with the commands:

```
>> hann250=hanning(250); 

>> smooth250=conv(signal,hann250,'same');
```

But I am not sure at all how to interpolate the data - what commands can I use and what would I type? I'm totally new to MATLAB! I am also not sure what interpolation method I need but I intend to try various one's and see (once I know how!). Thanks,

T

Comment: Check `interp1`. To see its documentation, type `help interp1` in Matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try spline interpolation:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spline.html

```
% read x, y from your file
xx = linspace(min(x), max(x), 1000); % generate 1000 equally spaced points
yy = spline(x,y,xx); % interpolate
plot(x,y); % original
hold all;
plot(xx,yy); % new
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html):

```
data = [0    1.7092
 115.0000    1.6766
 230.0000    1.6430
 345.0000    1.6095
 460.0000    1.5749
 575.0000    1.5409
 690.0000    1.5069
 806.0000    1.4733];

index_interp = 0:806; %// indices on which to interpolate
data_interp = interp1(data(:,1),data(:,2),index_interp,'linear');
```

There are other interpolation methods available in addition to `'linear'`; see the above link.